# Can the iPad use GPS data from a Garmin aera 660?

Tags: gnss

Can the iPad use GPS data from a Garmin aera 660 portable GPS unit? I assume this would happen via Bluetooth, if it's possible. I would like the more accurate WAAS data from the Garmin for use with CloudAhoy.

Comment: I can't answer your question directly but FWIW I've never succeeded in getting my Garmin GDL39 to talk to Cloudahoy. From what little I could find out, Garmin doesn't make it easy for third-party software to use their devices.

Answer (score 1):

Most bluetooth external GPS devices conform to NMEA and are compatible with CloudAhoy. I don't know if that's the case with Garmin Aera 660.

However, if used with Garmin Pilot, then you can always export GP's track log to CloudAhoy. (I'm associated with Cloudahoy)

Answer (score 1):

NMEA out is supported via USB by the [Aera 660](http://static.garmin.com/pumac/190-02017-20_D.pdf). I could find no documentation of this ability via bluetooth.

> The following formats are supported for connection of external devices: NMEA 0180, 0182, 0183 (versions 1.5, 2.0, 2.3, 3.01) pg173

A wireless process is Aera 660 to Garmin Pilot for logging and then to CloudAhoy.

> Using Bluetooth® connectivity via Garmin Connext technology, the [aera 660](https://buy.garmin.com/en-US/US/p/520775) easily interfaces with compatible devices to cut the clutter in your cockpit and improve your flying experience...
>
> Using your device’s built-in GPS receiver, optional GDL 39, GLO™ for Aviation or [Connext compatible configuration](https://buy.garmin.com/en-US/US/p/115856#overview)¹, Garmin Pilot provides full en route navigation on the rich, interactive moving map...
>
> Uploading the automatically created track log from Garmin Pilot [into CloudAhoy](http://help.cloudahoy.com/importing-flight-data/#data:%7B%22url%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fhelp.cloudahoy.com%2Ffrom-garmin-pilot%2F%22%7D) is a convenient alternative to logging the flight with the CloudAhoy app...